# Responsive full width image banner with fixed height using srcset

Tags: html, css, image, src

I am trying to implement a responsive full width (fixed height) image banner with the `srcset`attribute.
To support older browsers i am using [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) as a polyfill.

Basically i want a always 150px heigh full width banner, but with a different sized image depending von the `screen width`and the `device pixel ratio`.

The Problem is that `srcset` does not pick for example the `banner960x300`image if the `device pixel ratio` is 2.

Here is what i have tried:

```
<img srcset="/images/banner480x150.png 480w 1x,
             /images/banner960x300.png 480w 2x,
             /images/banner768x150.png 768w 1x,
             /images/banner1536x300.png 768w 2x,
             /images/banner992x150.png 992w 1x,
             /images/banner1984x300.png 992w 2x,
             /images/banner1200x150.png 1200w 1x,
             /images/banner2400x300.png 1200w 2x,
             /images/banner1920x150.png 1920w 1x,
             /images/banner3840x300.png 1920w 2x"
     sizes="100%"
     class="banner"
     style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">
```

and

```
<img srcset="/images/banner480x150.png 480w 150h,
             /images/banner960x300.png 960w 300h,
             /images/banner768x150.png 768w 150h,
             /images/banner1536x300.png 1536w 300h,
             /images/banner992x150.png 992w 150h,
             /images/banner1984x300.png 1984w 300h,
             /images/banner1200x150.png 1200w 150h,
             /images/banner2400x300.png 2400w 300h,
             /images/banner1920x150.png 1920w 150h,
             /images/banner3840x300.png 3840w 300h"
     sizes="100%"
     class="banner"
     style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">
```

I am not sure if this is the correct syntax for the `srcset`attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the solution:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="/images/banner1920x150.jpg 1x,
                                                /images/banner3840x300.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="/images/banner1200x150.jpg 1x,
                                               /images/banner2400x300.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/banner992x150.jpg 1x,
                                               /images/banner1984x300.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="/images/banner768x150.jpg 1x,
                                               /images/banner1536x300.jpg 2x">
    <img src="/images/banner480x150.jpg"
         srcset="/images/banner480x150.jpg 1x,
                 /images/banner960x300.jpg 2x"
         alt="Awesome banner"
         class="banner"
         style="width: 100%; height: 150px;>
</picture>
```

The relative 150px height is kept and the high resolution image is downloaded if the `device pixel ratio` is higher than `1x`.

Comment: Yeah, that syntax should be more or less identical to the one I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct syntax to do that. It seems to be based on the old, now defunct srcset spec, which was never implemented anywhere.

Regarding what you're trying to achieve, you could do that with art-direction and the `<picture>` element, but unless you can specify every possible viewport width and their corresponding image (and you can't), there would be viewport dimensions where your image height won't be a fixed 150px, so expect some distortion there.
It might be better to loosen the 150px height requirement between breakpoints (or use CSS clip to maintain it).

The syntax to do that would be something like the one below. There's no need to specify `sizes` since its default is `100vw` (so 100% of the viewport width, which is what you need).

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="/images/banner480x150.png 480w, /images/banner960x300.png 960w">
    <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/banner768x150.png 768w,
             /images/banner1536x300.png 1536w">
    <source media="(max-width: 992px)" srcset="/images/banner992x150.png 992w,
             /images/banner1984x300.png 1984w">
    <source media="(max-width: 1200px)" srcset="/images/banner1200x150.png 1200w,
             /images/banner2400x300.png 2400w">
    <img src="/images/banner1920x150.png" 
         srcset="/images/banner1920x150.png 1920w,
             /images/banner3840x300.png 3840w"
         class="banner"
         alt="This is an awesome banner!">
</picture>
```

Comment: I think i have found a solution. I posted it as an answer, maybe you can verify it. Anyway, Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction!