# Why is responsive images so off (my) reality?

Tags: css, responsive-design, picturefill

There is one simple task I want to achieve.
I have an image in a variable width container.
The container can have a width of 300, 400, 700, or 900 pixels. This is done by the means of media-queries
The image should take up all the width of that container. So it will be also 300, 400, 700, or 900 pixels wide.
The image should have different sources for all that width values. So I can serve smaller images on mobile phones.

I thought that this could be done with the `srcset` attribute of the `img` element, maybe under help of the `sizes` attribute. width something like this

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/abc/000" 
      alt="dummy" 
      srcset="
        http://dummyimage.com/900x200/abc/000 900w, 
        http://dummyimage.com/700x200/abc/000 700w, 
        http://dummyimage.com/400x200/abc/000 400w, 
        http://dummyimage.com/300x200/abc/000 300w
      " 
       />
```

But it's not working in that way, because the browser chooses the image in proportion to the width of the display port and not to that of the image itself.
Example with use of picturefill polyfill from http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/: http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/itBJy . This does not work, because it will take the one image that is the next size.

I could of course take that into account and change my srcset to this

```
      srcset="
        http://dummyimage.com/900x200/abc/000 999999w, 
        http://dummyimage.com/700x200/abc/000 900w, 
        http://dummyimage.com/400x200/abc/000 700w, 
        http://dummyimage.com/300x200/abc/000 400w
      "
```

This will work on the desktop, but fails on retina displays, because the device pixel ratio is taken into account here, but in a different way than with the media queries. And it is not useful, because the image should know about the width of the viewport and of the same width and that at compile time? No way. Image I use the image in a grid system. The image has different widthes if I'm in a 3 column grid on desktop devices and a 1 column grid on smart phones. That should not be in the responsibility of the image to calulate the ratio of width and viewport-width.

I did not have any luck with the `sizes` attribute as well (no example here). The reason is tha same as above. In the sizes attibute I say which amount of the viewport width should my image be wide according to media queries. This is so off. How should the image know?

So I came around with this solution. I setup a `data-srcset` attribute with the same syntax as the srcset attribute itself, but with a custom JavaScript programming. Example here: http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/tCqJI

```
jQuery(function($){
  var reg = /[\s\r\n]*(.*?)[\s\r\n]+([^\s\r\n]+w)[\s\r\n]*(,|$)/g;
  var regw = /(.*)w/;
  var sets, $set, set, myMatch, i, w, that, last;

  var checkData = function() {
    $('img[data-srcset]').each(function() {
      that = $(this);
      $set = that.data('srcset');
      sets = [];
      while(myMatch = reg.exec($set)) {
        set = {};
        set.src = myMatch[1];
        set.w = (myMatch[2].match(regw))[1];
        sets[set.w] = set;
      }
      w = that.width();
      last = 0;
      for (i in sets) {
        last = i;
        if (w <= i) {
          that.attr('src', sets[i].src);
          return;
        }
      }

      that.attr('src', sets[last].src);
    });
  };


  checkData();
  $(window).on('resize', checkData);
});
```

This works, but it feels wrong. But maybe not, as the specifications says for responsive images to behave just in the way that it does. But I feel that it's the wrong way. 90 % of use cases for responsive images won't work with the spec.

So am I wrong? Didn't I use the srcset in the defined way? Did I understand the spec incorrectly? And do the W3C and Responsive Images Community Group think in such a way apart from reality?

Comment: There are scripts like this that have been out for a few years. I think the best bet is adaptive-images php which serves up the correct size for different devices server side, no need for jquery or change in markup. Or you can use another server side technique such as mobile-detect and change the html.

Answer (score 1):

Are the smaller images scaled down versions of the bigger image? Or are they cropped (art direction)? If the latter, you should use `picture` and `source media`.

The reason the browser only uses the viewport for deciding which image to download is that it's the only thing that is available when the browser wants to download an image. The CSS (probably) isn't downloaded yet. So if you use `srcset`+`sizes`, you have to repeat the breakpoints and image widths in `sizes`.

Comment: In this case, they are art directed. But it should not matter. All the author and the browser should know is the width of the image. I tried with the picture element, but it seems to me, that it's even more complicated without haveing any benefit over the srcset approach. And I could not achieve what I want. And of course I have my css in the head part of my html, so the css *is* loaded at that time.

Comment: It does matter. If you do art direction, you should not use srcset, since with srcset the browser is free to choose any resource it wants. For art direction you want better control, right?

Comment: Of course i want better control. But `picture` doesn't give it to me. It's all related to media queries, but i need to relate to the image width, the viewport width.

Comment: Why can't you use the viewport? The CSS uses the viewport to set the image width.

Comment: Because the problem is more complicated in the real world than in my example. Image, using a grid system. The image may be in a container, that uses 12 of 12 columns, or in a container that uses only 6 of 12 columns. I don't want to create 12 different selectors for an image for 3 different viewport widthes for any different type of image use cases. That would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems like a duplicate of [Responsive full width image banner with fixed height using srcset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138326/responsive-full-width-image-banner-with-fixed-height-using-srcset/26139177)

Like zcorpan said, what you are trying to do falls under the "art-direction" use-case (since the different images have different proportions), so you should use the `<picture>` element, rather than srcset. See the other question's answers for a syntax example.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I don't want full width images in my case. I want the image to be 100% of the surrounding container element. And that cannot be achieved by `picture` as the sources are chosen by media queries.